# Create a file using Cp1250 in Java

Tags: java, file, character-encoding, cp1252, cp1250

I'm trying to create a file using the **Cp1250** charset:

```
out = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("/path/filename"), Charset.forName("Cp1250")));
```

However, when I detect the actual charset with [juniversalchardet](http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet), 
it says **WINDOWS-1252** which is **Cp1252** (according to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)).

Enca (`enca -L czech -g filename`) detects **ISO-8859-2**.

How could I set exactly **Cp1250** (or, using java.nio API name, **windows-1250**)?

Thank you

Karel

Comment: `Charset.forName("windows-1250")` ???

Comment: "Plain text" files generally carry no metadata about their character encoding. Detection classes use heuristics and statistics and are inherently unreliable. Switch to a file format with a strictly defined encoding scheme.

Comment: What is the content of this file, because it is next to impossible for a tool to distinguish between windows-1250 and windows-1252 as on the byte-level it will look identical, except with heuristics based on the frequency of occurrence of some characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any encoding detection program can only be heuristic when it comes to encodings which are basically *valid* for all files (e.g. ones which are always one byte per character and have a character mapped to every byte).

You should encode some text which you know would cause different results between [Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) and [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), and see what your code actually does. I suspect you'll find it's actually doing the right thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been using only "čača" as the file contents which did not contain all characters that are on different positions in these two charsets.